# The function template specialization when using tempates as argument

Tags: c++, templates

I want to write a function template to deal with the vectors, lists, sets, ...
and want to write the specialization function to deal with the map separately , 
when I wrote the following code and the compiler reports errors.

could any one help me how to modify it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

// test() for the vectors, lists, sets, ...

template <template <typename...> class T>
void test()
{
    T<string, int> x;
    //...
}

// specialize test() for map
template <>
void test <map<> class T>()
{

    T<string, int> x;
    //...
}


int main()
{
    test<map>();
    test<unordered_map>();
}
```

Comment: ;--------- I get following errors when using code::blocks+gcc4.7.1 to compile the old code

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -std=c++11 -g -c main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o main.cpp:138:16: error: wrong number of template arguments (0, should be 4) In file included from c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/map:61:0, from main.cpp:11: c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/bits/stl_map.h:90:11: error: provided for 'template class std::map' main.cpp:138:6: error: template-id 'test< >' for 'void test()' does not match any template declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template specialization should be:

```
template <>
void test <std::map>()
{

    std::map<string, int> x;
}
```

I changed the template parameter from `map<> class T` which is invalid syntax into `std::map`. And I changed `T<string, int>` into `std::map<string, int>` because the name `T` doesn't exist in the specialization.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the complete code which works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

template <template <typename...> class T, typename TN>
void test()
{
    cout << "---------- test case 1" << endl;
    T<TN, int> x;
}

template <template <typename...> class T>
void test()
{
    cout << "---------- test case 2" << endl;
    T<string, int> x;
}

template <> 
void test < map,string >()
{
    cout << "---------- test case 3" << endl;
    map<string, int> x;
}

template <> 
void test < map >()
{
    cout << "---------- test case 4" << endl;
    map<string, int> x;
}

int main()
{
    test<unordered_map,string>(); // trigging test case 1
    test<unordered_map>();        // trigging test case 2
    test<map,string>();           // trigging test case 3
    test<map>();                  // trigging test case 4
}
```